# Login to Magento 2.0 from external application

Tags: single-sign-on, magento2

I am into integration with Magento 2.0, however I have a cakePHP 2.0 application and I want the user to be already logged in after he successfully logged into my cakePHP application.
How can I implement such feature?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to SSO between 2 apps that are hosted in different domains is to use [SAML2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0)

In that standard there are 2 type of entities:

- Identity Provider (IdP). The entity that authenticates the user and send its info to the SP.
- Service Provider (SP). The entity that protect the app, is connected with the IdP and can make access control decision.

Since you are using PHP stack I recommend you to use the [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) software to deploy your IdP.

You will need to decide what gonna be your user data source, CakePHP or Magento, and disable registration and password reset on the source not selected.

So in your project you will need:

- Deploy an [IdP with simplesamlphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp) and use as [authentication source the database of your cakePHP](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/sqlauth:sql) app (if this source is the selected), removing user registration/password on Magento (otherwise connect Magento's database as your main user source and not let users to be registered on cakePHP).
- Enable [SAML on cakePHP](https://github.com/zl4bv/CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin)
- Enable [SAML on Magento2](https://marketplace.magento.com/sixtomartin-onelogin-module-saml2.html)

The advantage of using this standard instead of custom tricky SSOs mechanism is that you will be able to add to your SSO federation any other app (with SAML support) like Salesforce, Wordpress, Google Apps, Drupal, Joomla...

On [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b2rSJpzDkc) you can see the Magento2 extension in action (I'm using Onelogin as Identity provider). In [this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKTRkSEyUIA) you can see simpleSAMLphp in action with Magento1.

Note: I'm the author of the Magento2 SAML extension. Right now there is no other option to add SAML to a Magento2 app and is a complex task so I don't recommend to implement it yourself ;)

Comment: Will this SAML extension still work with the new PWA Studio REACT front ends that are intended to be standard soon? Also, my identity provider is Keycloak. It does support SAML, will the Magento SAML extension work with Keycloak?

Comment: Related to the PWA Studio, I had no idea yet on how this will be officially released and how it can affect the current login flow so can't confirm. But if is incompatible, I will work on a new release to make it compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. We're about to purchase your extension. Just a couple more questions. I Installed magento using aws marketplace with amistacx. That is for test purposes. If I purchase your extension and install it on that instance, will I be able to move the license to a production version later after spinning down the test magento? Also, what is the extent of the support you give for the extra $150 beyond the question and answer on the forums?

Comment: Test environment does not require License Key, so if you set it you can reuse in your prod site.

Comment: The $150 give you 3 hours of support, to help configuring the extension or make some customization.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand about the test environment not requiring a license key. By test environment I mean, I quickly got magento running in AWS by using amistacx. It still has a custom domain and ssl certificate associated with it. In the future I plan to replace amistacx with a better implementation of magento. When I tear down the amistacx environment, will I be able to re-install the extension in a new magento? Are you saying, if I enter the license key, then something happens to my environment where I have to re-install, I won't be able to?

Comment: If the domain is a test domain the license key can be reused in a prod new domain.

Comment: If you 1st install the extension in a magento1 instance and then you migrate to another instance, if you keep using the same domain all will be ok, if you use a new prod domain then you need a new license key